# parse RSS feed with PERL using XML:LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, rss

I am in the unfortunate position of needing to parse a RSS feed since there is no other way to obtain the data.  I have a Perl script that has worked before to parse an XML file.  I figured I could modify it to do the same for the RSS feed so I can get the data into a format that is easier use.  with that in mind i have modified my file.  But it doesn't actually seem to be finding any data to pull from the feed.  Here is the core of the code.

```
foreach my $channel ($root->findnodes('channel')) {
  foreach my $item ($root->findnodes('item')) {
    my $guid = $item->findvalue('guid');
    my $title = $item->findvalue('title');
    my $link = $item->findvalue('link');
    my $description = $item->findvalue('description');
    my $pubdate = $item->findvalue('pubdate');
    print DATA "INSERT INTO events VALUES ( \"$guid\", \"$title\", \"$link\",\"$description\", \"$pubdate\" ); \n";
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Side note: look into using [DBI placeholders and bind values](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) for your database inserts. You don't want Little Bobby Tables to make a visit.

Comment: The XML extraction looks fine. Please provide a minimal runnable demonstration of the problem. (The database code is completely broken, though. Consider what happens if `$title` or `$description` contains a `"`, a newline, or something far more nefarious.)

Comment: I understand your security concerns, however the purpose of this script is to dump the data into a read only sqlite data file.  This file will not be used for web consumption.  The purpose of this script is to generate a new standalone sqlite data file on the fly.

Comment: Have you considered using, e.g., [XML::RSS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-RSS/)? Writing your own RSS parser is typically a doomed strategy.

Comment: You are probably right.  I will investigate XML:RSS as this really isn't a long term solution.

Comment: figured out part of the issue.  Turns out I had it wrong.
     foreach my $item ($root->findnodes('item')) should have been
     foreach my $item ($channel->findnodes('item')) {

Comment: @oljones, And that's why I asked for a runnable demo. I would have found that in 30s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting aside for one moment the excellent suggestion from [Richard Simões](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91768/richard-simoes) to use XML::RSS ...

I think the main problem you're hitting is to do with XML namespaces.  Consider this line of your script:

```
$root->findnodes('channel')
```

It is looking for *an element of type 'channel'*, but your source document probably doesn't contain such an element.  What you should be looking for is something like: *an element of type 'channel' in the namespace identified by the URI 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/'*.

Working with namespaces is fiddly.  There are two types: a default namespace (eg: xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"); and namespaces declared with a prefix (e.g.: xmlns:rss="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/").  In either case, the only thing that matters is the namespace URI.  The prefix declared in the document (e.g.: 'rss:') is irrelevant to your script.

To use namespaces with libxml, you need to declare your own prefix for each namespace URI and then use that prefix in your calls to findnodes.  You can choose a prefix that is the same as the one in the document or different - it doesn't matter as long as the URI is the same.  You need to use an XML::LibXML::XPathContext object to associate namespace URIs with prefixes and then route your queries through that context object.

This is a version of your script that's probably closer to what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file('slashdot.rss');
my $root   = $doc->documentElement();

my $xc     = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $root );
$xc->registerNs( rss => 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/' );

foreach my $channel ($xc->findnodes('rss:channel')) {
    foreach my $item ($xc->findnodes('rss:item')) {
        my $guid = $xc->findvalue('rss:guid', $item);
        my $title = $xc->findvalue('rss:title', $item);
        my $link = $xc->findvalue('rss:link', $item);
        my $description = $xc->findvalue('rss:description', $item);
        my $pubdate = $xc->findvalue('rss:pubDate', $item);
        print "INSERT INTO events VALUES ( \"$guid\", \"$title\", \"$link\",\"$description\", \"$pubdate\" ); \n";
    }
}
```

The document you're trying to parse probably uses a different version of RSS and therefore a different RSS namespace URI - that's just one of many reasons to use an RSS module rather than try to do it manually.

As [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) pointed out, interpolating values into SQL is really a poor idea.  In your example you are generating SQL with double-quoted string literals (you probably meant to use single quotes). This will fail if any of the values you extract from RSS contain a double quote character.  Single and double quote characters are extremely likely to occur in RSS.